# `make-rename-transformer` not working inside other macro using quote

Tags: macros, racket, rename

I have the following code that composes a traditional macro `eat` which uses a quote (`'(eating food)`), with a `make-rename-transformer` macro that is supposed to transform `lunch` into `sandwich`. The full code is:

```
#lang racket

(require (for-syntax syntax/parse))

(define-syntax lunch (make-rename-transformer #'sandwich))

(define-syntax (eat stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_ food)
     #''(eating food)]))

(eat lunch)
```

Because `lunch` is just a rename transfomer for `sandwich`, I would expect it to evaluate to `(eat sandwich)`, and thus `'(eating sandwich)`, but when I run it, I get:

```
'(eating lunch)
```

Which is not what I expected. Is there any way I can modify this so that rename transforms in quotes are followed? (As if I had used the `list` function rather than `quote`.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is just an order of expansion. Unlike functions which, to a first approximation anyway, evaluate inside out. Macros by nature expand outside in, which is an intrinsic property of macro expansion in languages like Racket.

So, the problem is that the first step of macro expa

```
#lang racket
(define-syntax lunch (make-rename-transformer #'sandwich))
'(eating lunch)
```

At this point `lunch` is no longer an identifier, but just a datum, so the rename transformer won't apply here.

What you need to do is tell the macro expander to expand `food` before you place it in the quote and turn it into datum. Racket's macro expander contains this functionality, [`local-expand`], if you combine this with `#:when` (`syntax/parse`'s version of [`with-syntax`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stx-patterns.html?q=with-syntax#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fstxcase-scheme..rkt%29._with-syntax%29%29)), you can get the macro to evaluate `food` first.

Putting it all together, your code looks like:

```
#lang racket

(require (for-syntax syntax/parse))

(define-syntax lunch (make-rename-transformer #'sandwich))

(define-syntax (eat stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_ food)
     #:with expanded-food (local-expand #'food 'expression #f)
     #''(eating expanded-food)]))

(eat lunch)
```

And when you run this, you get:

```
'(eating sandwich)
```